# Find the Common first_name from Django Auth user Model

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

i need to find out the common first_name ( not case sensitive ) of the mail info@something.com

i'm using `MongoDb and MongoEngine` . how the query should be in normal ORM

User list:

```
first_name = 'Anish Menon'
email = 'info@something.com'



first_name = 'Hari Dev'
email = 'info@something.com'


first_name = 'anish MenoN'
email = 'info@something.com'
```

Initial:

```
Users = User.objects.filter(email='info@something.com')

for user in Users:
  --------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
import operator
```

Then in your loop, get a list of the first_name in lowercase:

```
list = []
list.append(user.first_name.lower()) # to have lowercase strings
```

then, count the iteration of the first_name:

```
dict = {}
for el in list:
    if el in dict:
        dict[el] += 1
    else:
        dict[el] = 1

max(dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] # This is your result
```

Enjoy :)